# Return only ONE object from an EntitySet

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have these two tables mapped in Linq: *Persons* and *Contracts*.
I also have a global variable *DateTime DateOfInteres*.

When I map the Persons table I would like to have a property returning a **single** contract: the valid contract at the DateOfInteres.

Basically, *Contracts* has, amongst others, these three properties: *bool IsActive, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate*.

After mapping the tables I defined this EntitySet in the Person class:

*EntitySet _lct = new EntitySet();
[Association(Storage="_lct", ThisKey="Id", OtherKey="PersonId"]*

Usually the next step is to define a *public IEnumerable Contracts* containing all the contracts of that person but I need this:

**one** *public Contract ActiveContract* meaning the contract with:
*(IsActive==true) && ( StartDate <= DateOf Interes ) && ( EndDate >= DateOfInteres)*

Thus, when creating the MVVM objects the *ActiveContract* and it's properties with be immediately accesible.

Any idea on how this can be implemented?

Thank you,
Daniel

======
Something like this, I think:

```
    private EntitySet<Contract> _lctr = new EntitySet<Contract>();
    [Association(Storage = "_lctr", ThisKey = "Id", OtherKey = "PersonId")]

    public Contract ActiveContract
    {
        get {
return _lctr.Where(ct => (ct.IsActive == true) &&
            ( ct.StartDate <= DateOf Interes ) && ( ct.EndDate >= DateOfInteres))
            .OrderByDescending(ct => ct.DataInceput)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Contacts.Where(x=> [*PutYourConditionsHere*]).GroupBy(x => x.PersonID).Select(x => x.First())
```

Comment: A short explanation and an example for a condition would make your answer way more valuable.

Comment: Thank you Jitendra Gupta but that's not the ides. I don't want to query the Contracts table (like in your example).
I want to have a property of the Person class returning the ActiveContract.

As I was saying, I'm having the <i>EntitySet<Contracts> _lct</i> and based on that I wand to define the <i>ActiveContract</i> property.

Something like this, I think:
public Contract ActiveContract
{